# javax.management.remote.misc: The server has decided to close this client connection

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, startup

When I was debugging the startup process of my SpringBoot application, sometimes it will show up the following warning log:

```
WARN 3781 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.remote.misc             : The server has decided to close this client connection.
```

After some searching, I found out the package **javax.management.remote** has something to do with RMI, but still can't figure out the reason, Can someone explain why this warning is shown?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA, OpenJDK17, spring boot of version 2.6, and JPA, p6spy as dependencies.